"Edit top ... rows" does not work anymore after having launched stored procedures
I have no idea whether this question should be asked here or on the DBA website:
I'm working with SSMS (SQL-Server Management Studio), hereby the version info from the "Help, About" box:



---
v18.12




SQL Server Management Studio
15.0.18420.0


SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)
16.100.47021.0+7eef34a564af48c5b0cf0d617a65fd77f06c3eb1


Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools
15.0.19750.0


Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)
10.0.19041.5007


Microsoft MSXML
3.0 4.0 6.0


Microsoft .NET Framework
4.0.30319.42000


Operating System
10.0.19045



Recently, I've been working with some stored procedures: sp_trace_create, sp_trace_setevent, sp_trace_setfilter and sp_trace_setstatus.
Once I worked with those stored procedures, I already remarked that the "Edit" feature did not work anymore: right-click on a tablename, choose Edit Top ... Rows, I only see an empty screen:

In the meantime, I've stopped all traces:
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 0; -- Stop the trace
EXEC sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2;

I've restarted SSMS, I've restarted my PC, but nothing helps.
Windows event log does not contain any "Error" logs, as far as I know.

What is the server version? For example, SSMS 18.x does not support SQL Server 16+ (2022). See the answers here for similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74613517/edit-top-200-rows-not-working-for-sql-server-16-0-express-edition

You're right: nothing a good-old update can't fix :-)

SSMS version 18.x does not support SQL Server 16.x (2022) and newer
See also: "Edit Top 200 Rows" not working for SQL Server 16.0 - Express Edition
